SetUp Not running first in nUnit
Setup fixture is not running first in my base class. This causes tests to fail as it is meant to initialise some contexts there. I can put the SetUp in the Test class but I would much rather not.
It fails in the next class acceptPaymentsFlow, when trying to access the api and web context
Unsure what's happening.
Testbase:
    public class TestBase
    {
        public ApiStepContext ApiContext;
        public WebStepContext WebContext;
        protected AssertionValidator Validator { get; set; }
        
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public static void BeforeTestRun()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(VisualTestingConfigurationProvider.OutputFilePath))
            {
                Directory.Delete(VisualTestingConfigurationProvider.OutputFilePath, true);
            }
            if (Directory.Exists(VisualTestingConfigurationProvider.DifferencesFilePath))
            {
                Directory.Delete(VisualTestingConfigurationProvider.DifferencesFilePath, true);
            }
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeTest()
        {
            ApiContext = new ApiStepContext();
            WebContext = new WebStepContext();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void AfterTest()
        {
            if (WebContext.IsPageOpen)
            {
                WebContext.WebPage.CloseAsync().Wait();
            }
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public static void AfterTestRun()
        {
            PageFactory.DisposeWebEnvironment();
            FrameworkLogger.LogTestRunEnd();
            LoggerFactory.CloseLogging();
        }
    }

Test class -
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class AcceptPayments : TestBase
    {
        private AcceptPaymentFlow _acceptPaymentFlow;

        public AcceptPayments()
        {
            _acceptPaymentFlow = new AcceptPaymentFlow(ApiContext, WebContext);
        }
        

        [Test]
        public async Task testRun()
        {
            await _acceptPaymentFlow.GivenCallCreatePaymentEndpoint();
            await _acceptPaymentFlow.GivenIFollowAuthUrlPayments();
        }
    }

